# Fujifilm mini evo

Tags: fujifilm-instax

I took photo in my mini evo and it is saved in my SD.

I took the SD to transfer it to my PC however it was emptied, both internal storage and also my SD. Which was weird.

Thought it was the adaptor that corrupted my SD card, put in the SD card and tried taking new photo.  But this time only able to view the newly taken in the PC, except the previous photo.

Any ideas? Kindly advise me what should I do please. I want to get all the photo from my travels

Comment: Your question is the same as the one you originally responded to with "I experienced the same issue too." I have closed this as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I feel hopeless as I dont get an answer to this, thats why im asking again

Comment: Seems like you really have a problem with me asking question here.

Comment: Plus you were the one who told me to ask new question and deleted the previous one

Comment: Plus the person who commented was able to view the SD card while I CANT. I just wanted to seek answers here.

Comment: I absolutely don't have a problem with you asking questions here. But please understand how Stack Exchange sites work. Your question is a duplicate of the other question. We don't do duplicates here. Please see the Help Center topic, [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)